# Sending props two times from parent component to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting map undefined when i am sending props Two times as separate components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state =  {
    todos: [
    {id : 1 , content: "lets sleep"},
    {id: 2, content:"lets eat "}
  ]}

  deletTodo =  (id) => {
    console.log(id)
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container">
      <h1 className="center blue-text">Todo's</h1>
         <Todo todo = {this.state.todos} />
         { <Todo deletTodo = {this.deletTodo}/> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It is throwing me map of undefined  but the following code does the trick i don't know why any one explain

```
 <Todo todo = {this.state.todos} deletTodo= {this.deletTodo}/>
```

The following is my Todo.js where i am  getting the props

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Todo extends Component {

    render() {
       return (
            <div className= "todos collection">
            {
            this.props.todo.map((td)=>{
            return (
                <div  className="collection-item" key ={td.id} >
             <span>{td.content}</span>
             </div>
              )})}


            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the usage of component will create seperate instances. Only the props that you provide in that instance will be available as this.props.

in `<Todo todo = {this.state.todos} />` only todo prop is available and deletTodo is not available. In `{ <Todo deletTodo = {this.deletTodo}/> }` only deletTodo is available and todos prop is not available. This is the reason you will get the error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. You can fix this by providing a default prop so that none of the props are ever undefined.

```
Todo.defaultProps = {
  todo: [],
  deletTodo: () => null,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your state in a constructor

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
           //set state here
    }
```